# What does "Handlock" refer to?

Tags: hearthstone

I hear this term in reference to Warlocks. I think it's about how Warlock's keep a ton of burn spells in their hand and hit you directly. Not sure if this is accurate or not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Handlock is a Warlock deck that includes Twilight Drakes and Giants. They're called Handlocks because their strategy involves tapping on their early turns to get a big hand quickly to get big Twilight Drakes and cheap Mountain Giants.

Comment: DKMR did a [card-by-card breakdown of a handlock deck](http://hearthstone.blizzpro.com/2014/05/23/deck-of-the-week-14-handlock/) that is very useful if you want more detail.